# Regular expression - capitalize first letter and remove spaces

Tags: regex

Can somebody help me create the following regular expression:

- Remove spaces
- Remove any other characters except letters and numbers
- Capitalize first letter of every word (CamelCase)

**Example**

Source: This is my document - version 2 
Result: ThisIsMyDocumentVersion2

Thanks,

Comment: You must show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: 1) Why do you need a regex to do this? It would be simpler using straight string handling functions. 2) What regex engine are you using? Syntax and functionality differs between them. 3) What expressions have you tried so far to do this yourself that aren't working?

Comment: I am using Nintex Workflow to rename files. It has the action to perform a regex on a string. I was able to find samples that do one of the things from my list but not all of them. Unfortunately I don't know regex that much to combine it myself.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably your regexp

```
var stc = "This is my document - version 2",
 result = stc.replace(/[^\w]+(\w)/g, (m,n) => n.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance in this subject but it looks more like a script than just a plain regular expression. Only regular expression will work for me. I just figured out that I can run regex multiple times to achieve items from my list one at a time. Maybe I can solve it this way.

Comment: The regexp in JavaScript notation is `/[^\w]+(\w)/g` however in any language you have to utilize it by some means to complete the action.